# How to get object from many to one relation, by some property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class FuturePlan {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int fpId;
    private String about;
    private Date travelDate;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Location location;

    ....contructors and get/set
```

...and

```
@Entity
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int lId;
    private String lName;
    ....contructors and get/set
```

How to get all `futurePlan` instances where `location.name == "Something"`?

Comment: I'm making a service layer.

Comment: Do you have to use HQL, SQL or something more specific?

Comment: Criteria would be the best solution. But another solution would be great also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can very well use native Query something like below:

```
 String q="select * from employer employer,employee where employer.id=
                    employee.employerId and employee.location='xyz'";
Query query= em.createNativeQuery(q,Object[].class);
List<Object[]> students= query.getResultList();
```

2. You can also achieve the same results by using HQL as well.
3. You can use Criteria Query too.